# Open/Close Menu Condition

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I am creating a small slide out menu without using any library. By using UIDynamics I have been able to slide open the menu by clicking on an IBAction button.

I wanted to ask how can I close the menu by clicking on the same btn. The menu can be closed by clicking on another btn e.g. the "Close" btn in the menu slide but I also want to close it by clicking on the same menu btn which opens it.

This is the function which shows the menu

```
-(BOOL)showMenu:(BOOL)yesNO{

    //cleaning the screen of any behaviors
    [self.animator removeAllBehaviors];

    //animation will go from side to side
    CGFloat graxityDirectionX = (yesNO) ? 0.1 : -1.0;

    //detecting the collision of the menu
    CGFloat collision = (yesNO) ? menuWidth : -menuWidth;

    //insitating the gravity and telling it work on the menu
    UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.menuView]];

    gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(graxityDirectionX, 0);

    //adding the animation
    [self.animator addBehavior:gravity];

    //instaniating the collision and telling the menu were to stop
    UICollisionBehavior *collisionMenu = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.menuView]];

    //telling the menu where and what to collide it by using an invisible line
    [collisionMenu addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"menuBoundry" fromPoint:CGPointMake(collision, 580) toPoint:CGPointMake(collision, 0)];

    //adding the collision
    [self.animator addBehavior:collisionMenu];

    //setting the bounce
    UIDynamicItemBehavior *menuBounce = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[self.menuView]];
    menuBounce.elasticity = 0;
    [self.animator addBehavior:menuBounce];

   return YES;
}
```

And this is how I am calling it in the IBAction

```
- (IBAction)menuAction:(id)sender {
   [self showMenu:YES];
}
```

I have tried different types of if statements but I cannot get it to close.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a variable that stores the state of whether the menu is shown or not? Or am ethos that returns that information that you can call?

Comment: What do you mean about the state of the state of the menu?

The menu is hidden from the view using -menuWidth and by animation it slides in the middle.

Comment: have tried to operate with the `selected` state of the button?

Comment: No I did not try that...thanks for pointing it out. But I also want it to remain selected once the menu is opened. This will not pose a problem right

Comment: You can also check the origin of the view you are animating(self.viewMenue), like if the viewmenu.orgin.x > somePoint means it is open, else close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misunderstood the dynamic behaviour. Ok I suggest to use a BOOL for this. Declare BOOL

```
BOOL isMenuVisible;
```

and then use it in IBAction

```
- (IBAction)menuAction:(id)sender {
    if(isMenuVisible == NO){
       self.isMenuVisible = YES;
       [self showMenu:self.isMenuVisible];
    }else{
       self.isMenuVisible = NO;
       [self showMenu:self.isMenuVisible];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shorter version: `self.isMenuVisible = !self.isMenuVisible; [self showMenu:self.isMenuVisible];`

Comment: Thank you guys! Problem solved!

There is one thing which I want to ask. When I added the "BOOL isMenuVisible" inside the IBAction method the menu did not work but when I declared it in the interface section it worked perfectly. Why did it not work when I declared it in the IBAction?

Comment: Because it goes out of scope when the method completed.

Comment: Because when you declare it in the interface it scope is whole class and it persist its value until dealloc call on class where as if you declare it in menuAction. On calling menuAction every time you are declaring a new variable isMenuVisible whose default value is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Never use boolean for this task. As you have menu width in your method "showMenu". Take a class level property assign menu width to it. Apply a check in your method "menuAction". If you menu width is greater than 0 it means you have to close it. Incase if it is less than zero it means you have to  show it.

Comment: I have defined menuWidth at the top globally after the import statement. You are saying not to use bool, should I change bool to void in the "showMenu" mtd?

Also menuWidth is set to -ve so that it does not appear in the view, with animation it is sliding in. So how can I perform a check if the menuWidth is already fixed?